# How to reduce the row size when the multi line data is removed from Jface Tvaleviewer

Tags: jface

Using OwnerDrawLabelProvider() I am creating a multi-line table cells, so all rows are now of same size, if I delete a multiline cell and reload the table contents , all the rows still have the size of multiline row . When I close and open my application window the row size changes to single row. Without reopening the the window, how can I achieve this ?

I tried using viewer.setInput(null) and then  viewer.setInput(data) it still behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Eclipse bug [130024](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=130024) describes this. It doesn't look like this will be fixed.